# Calling React Query `refetch` with an additional parameter

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a `useQuery` fetching some data that is by default cached on the server. But sometimes, when a button is clicked, I want to send an additional parameter (`force=true`) that will force the server to refresh the data for that same query. I'm not able to do that properly:

```
const {data, refetch} = useQuery(['myQuery', id], () => goFetch({id}).then(response => response.data))
```

Ideally, that would be something like this:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    refetch({force: true})
}
```

but that doesn't work.

One workaround is having a `useState` like this:

```
const [force, setForce] = useState(false)
const {data} = useQuery(['myQuery', id, force], () => goFetch({id, force}).then(response => response.data))

const handleClick = () => {
    setForce(true)
}
```

Kinda works, but then I have to set the `force` parameter back to `false`, and it's going to be refetched again when it changes. Is there a more elegant solution that you would recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't actually need force and are using that to "trick" react query into thinking it needs to refetch.

In that case invalidate the query instead, this removes the query cache forcing the query to be called again.

ref: https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/query-invalidation

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-wave-k93512?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Forcing the refetch is a signal for the SERVER to get new data and not use the cached one. It's not about React Query's cached data...

Comment: In that case I do not believe I understand your issue. Perhaps mentioning that you can pass an onSuccess method to react query and reset your force variable in there is what you are looking for, if so I updated the example to show its use.

Comment: I think we're on the right track now, but there's still a slight problem:

In `handleClick` in your example, I would instead put `setForce(true)`, meaning, I require the service to reload the data it's going to send me. Then, in `onSuccess`, it switches it back to `false`, but then the query gets reloaded again (because the query key changes). It's mostly OK, but it calls the service twice unnecessarily.

Comment: Sure, you could do something like keep force in a useRef and access it directly from the useQuery fetch method instead of as a query key, resetting it onSuccess. useRef doesn't cause a rerender so changing its value wont call useQuery again. https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-wave-k93512?file=/src/App.tsx